# The unicode can not be demonstrated in python

Tags: python-3.x

I try to print an unicode which is '\U0001f4a9'
but it always gives the code not the character.

```
>>>mystery = '\U0001f4a9'
>>>mystery
'\U0001f4a9'
```

BTW, the version of my python is 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're not actually printing it, just showing its representation in the REPL.

```
3>> print(mystery)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#42>", line 1, in <module>
    print(mystery)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1343, in write
    return self.shell.write(s, self.tags)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode character '\U0001f4a9' in position 0: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk This is what i get. @Ignacio

Comment: And? Do it in the REPL in a terminal instead.

Comment: Wow, it works.....but why it's that? I believe I initiate the same python3.5 in Terminal.

Comment: Read the exception closely.

Comment: I wiki it. Thank you!:)